# Customize magneto native captcha appearance, Change amount of lines and dots

Tags: magento2.3

I want to change the layout of my captcha on contact form. I need to decrease the amount of lines and dots it contains so, a user can see the text more clearly.Does anyone have any idea how to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open /vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Captcha/Image.php

**Find this below line :**

protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 100; // For dots
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 5; // For lines

**Replace with**

protected $_dotNoiseLevel = 50;
protected $_lineNoiseLevel = 3;

Save it and clean cache.